# Difference between datetime? and nullable<DateTime>

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I need to know is there a difference between

```
DateTime? obj
```

And

```
Nullable<DateTime> obj
```

If it is the case, what are their use cases?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no difference.  The former is syntactic sugar for the second.  They compile to the exact same thing, `Nullable<DateTime>`, building identical IL.

```
void Main()
{
    DateTime? test1 = DateTime.Now;
    Nullable<DateTime> test2 = DateTime.Now;
}
```

IL for `DateTime?`

```
IL_0001:  ldloca.s    00 // test1
IL_0003:  call        System.DateTime.get_Now
IL_0008:  call        System.Nullable<System.DateTime>..ctor
```

IL for `Nullable<DateTime>`

```
IL_000E:  ldloca.s    01 // test2
IL_0010:  call        System.DateTime.get_Now
IL_0015:  call        System.Nullable<System.DateTime>..ctor
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference. `DateTime?` is a shorter way of writing `Nullable<DateTime>`. The actual type is `Nullable<DateTime>`

Answer (score 1):

As [MSDN suggests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx):

> The syntax T? is shorthand for [Nullable{T}](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx), where T is a value type. The two forms are interchangeable.

There is no difference, as you can see in the following decompiled MSIL code:

[image: Nullables]

when this is the original source:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DateTime? time = null;

    Nullable<DateTime> obj = null;

    if (false)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(time + " " + obj);
    }
}
```

both compile to `Nullable<DateTime>`. `DateTime?` is just a syntax sugar.

Comment: Downvoter please explain so I can make the answer better.

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2cf62fcy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> Nullable types can represent all the values of an underlying type, and
>   an additional null value. Nullable types are declared in one of two
>   ways:
>
> System.Nullable<T> variable
>
> -or-
>
> T? variable

Meaning they are equivalents. This behaviour however is not specific for type `DateTime` but for any other valuetype.